# Displaying BLOB data in a Browser

Tags: c#

I need to display my BLOB data directly into the IE Browser without saving a temporary file on the hard Disk.

I have successfully implemented the method of retrieving the file from the blob.

Please help me out or direct me to good articles on how to acheive this functionality.

Im using Visual Studio 2005, C#.NET and Oracle

Comment: How does it need to be displayed? As text, an image, pdf?

Comment: Im saving a .mht file to the BLOB to file and I need to display the data as a .mht in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following in an HTTP handler :

```
context.Response.ContentType = "multipart/related"; // I think...
context.Response.Write(<blob data here>);
```

Now this relies on a browser - IE, firefox - that can handle mht files..

If you want to parse the mht file and return html etc.. that would be a whole different scenario!

Answer (score 0):

If you've already code that saves it as a file then all you need to do is to change that to write it to the Response.OutputStream stream instead of the file stream.